# Entity update options in Spring/JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a **Vehicle** entity which has many attributes(around 30+ attributes).

I am trying to understand what is the best way to update entities with a large number of field attributes.

For example if a particular object(i.e. table row in the DB) like vehicle has to be updated with new values, what are the possible options ?

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "vehicle_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long vehicleId;
    private String vehicleName;
    private String makeYear;
    private String makeLocation;
    private String Brand;
    //**20 such other attributes**

    @ManyToOne(nullable=false)
    private Warehouse warehouse;
    //owner of the relationship

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicle", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Customer customers;

    //other such @OneToMany attributes

}
```

**Option 1 is**

```
public void updateVehicle(Vehicle vehicle){
    vehicle_existing = vehicleRepo.findOne(vehicle.getVehicleId());
    vehicle_existing = vehicleRepo.save(bid);
}
```

But this results in **certain fields of vehicle_existing being over-written to null/empty** if vehicle object being passed in doesn't have that particular field in the json.

**Option 2 is** to have defensive adders and add each particular value of the bean if it is not empty as below

```
public void addVehicleValues(Vehicle vehicle, Vehicle vehicle_existing){
    if (vehicle.vehicleId !=null && !vehicle.vehicleId.isEmpty()){
        //add the vehicleId to the existing vehicle ID in DB
        vehicle_existing.vehicleId = vehicle.vehicleId;     
    } 
    ** and so on for other fields ...including the @OneToMany associations
}
```

This seems tedious and non-elegant, but could work since the idea is to add only non-null and non-empty fields and that is what this does.

**Option 3** that i have in mind is a DTO, but am not really sure if that is the right way forward.

Given these options, what is the general practice for updating entities with large number of fields ? I am using `Spring` & `JPA`, but I think this is a common use case.

Comment: hibernate provides you with a `merge()` method, which should properly update the given object based on the information you pass in. if you have incomplete data you want to insert, which is generally very bad, you should first fetch the object you want to update and then change the required fields and insert/update it

Comment: Yes, vehicleRepo.save(bid) i mentioned above includes merge() in JPA. If you see my Option1, that is exactly what i am doing, fetching and updating. But if there is incomplete data and **there are a large number of fields** selective update through Option 2 suggested above, becomes tedious and hence the question :)

Comment: "But this results in certain fields of vehicle_existing being over-written to null/empty if vehicle object being passed in doesn't have that particular field in the json." That's how Spring works. If the JSON has defined attributes that you don't declare in the constructor signature, they will be null. When using Spring Data, you can define @PersistenceConstructor. But I think that feature is only available when using MongoDB. Isn't there any other way you can tell Spring how to instantiate objects from your mysql db?

Comment: thats what i think you have to do if you can't ensure complete data

Comment: I am wondering if there are other options ?

Comment: To update only modified fileds of enity use `org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate`. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-dynamicupdate

Comment: Thanks @JaySmith that seems promising, although i was hoping not to use Hibernate annotations. Quite useful though.

Comment: I would use a DTO containing exactly, and only, the fields that have been submitted in the form. You can validate that this form DTO is correct and valid, and then just get the persistent entity, copy the DTO fields to the persistent entity, and NOT use save(), as it's unnecessary: theentity is managed and all the changes made to the entity will be saved automatically at the end of the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this class:

```
public class NullAwareBeanUtil {
    private static String[] getNullPropertyNames(Object source) {
        final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
        java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[] pds = src.getPropertyDescriptors();

        Set<String> emptyNames = new HashSet<>();
        for (java.beans.PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
            Object srcValue = src.getPropertyValue(pd.getName());
            if (srcValue == null || srcValue instanceof Set<?> || srcValue instanceof List<?>) {
                emptyNames.add(pd.getName());
            }
        }
        String[] result = new String[emptyNames.size()];
        return emptyNames.toArray(result);
    }

    // then use Spring BeanUtils to copy and ignore null
    public static void copyProperties(Object src, Object target) {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, target, getNullPropertyNames(src));
    }
}
```

and in the service class, where "product" is the object containing attributes to modified:

```
Product productToUpdate = findOne(product.getId());

NullAwareBeanUtil.copyProperties(product, productToUpdate);

Product updatedProduct = save(productToUpdate);
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks.